# xslt template- how do I pass in the attribute and its value?

Tags: templates, xslt

I'm working with some XML where the nodes have lots of attributes, and I'm creating an FO PDF file (report) using XSL.  I'm trying to create a template that takes a specific attribute on the current node, and create an `fo:block` that will have some basic formatting.

Here is a template that creates a big list of all the attributes and values on one node.

XSL:

```
<xsl:template name="createAttributeAndValueList">
    <xsl:param name="node" select="." />
    <xsl:for-each select="$node/@*">
        <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(),':   ')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

However, there are times when I only want to get one or two of these attributes out, instead of all of them off the node. I'm guessing this is something that would be really obvious, but that I haven't figured out yet due to my inexperience.

I am trying to do the same formatting, but I just can't seem to get the syntax right to be able to pass in my value to the parameter, and get what I want.  Here's what I have:

XSL:

```
<xsl:template name="createAttributeValuePair">
    <xsl:param name="attribute" select="." />
    <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(),':   ')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

And here's how I'm trying to call it:
XSL:

```
<fo:block font-weight="normal" margin-left="6pt">
    <xsl:call-template name="createAttributeValuePair">
        <xsl:with-param name="attribute"                                     
                        select="/device:DevicePatientEncounter/device:Encounter/
                                     device:Followup/@UnderlyingRhythm"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</fo:block>
```

where my XML looks like this:

```
<DevicePatientEncounter xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                        GeneratedTime="2011-12-14T13:36:05" 
                        EncounterDate="2011-11-15T11:04:54" 
                        xmlns="device">
    <Encounter>
        <Followup UnderlyingRhythm="Sinus bradycardia" 
                  UnderlyingRhythmRateBpm="44" 
                  IsPmDependent="false" 
                  PresentingRhythm="Atrial fibrillation" 
                  BatteryChargeSeconds="5" 
                  AutoCapFrequency="3 Years" 
                  LastCapacitorFormDate="2011-10-25T00:00:00" 
                  BatteryLongevity="0" 
                  BatteryVoltage="11" 
                  BatteryStatus="MOL"/>
    </Encounter>
</DevicePatientEncounter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes:

- You're passing an attribute to `createAttributeValuePair` but you never do anything with the parameter
- You're looping over `@*` in this template, but the template seems designed to output the name and value of a single attribute
- In addition, `call-template` does not change the current node, so it's not really clear what element's attributes are being iterated in the loop

I'm guessing you're looking for something like this:

```
<xsl:template name="createAttributeValuePair">
    <xsl:param name="attribute" select="."/>
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(name($attribute),':   ')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$attribute"/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

Here's a complete demo:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" 
                xmlns:device="device">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:block font-weight="normal" margin-left="6pt">
            <xsl:call-template name="createAttributeValuePair">
                <xsl:with-param name="attribute" 
                      select="/device:DevicePatientEncounter/device:Encounter/
                                  device:Followup/@UnderlyingRhythm"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="createAttributeValuePair">
        <xsl:param name="attribute" select="."/>
        <fo:block>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(name($attribute),':   ')"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$attribute"/>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The following output is produced when given your example XML:

```
<fo:block xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:device="device"
          font-weight="normal"
          margin-left="6pt">
   <fo:block>UnderlyingRhythm:   Sinus bradycardia</fo:block>
</fo:block>
```